# ROS2, TypeError when publishing custom message to Topic (python)

Tags: python, typeerror, ros, ros2

I have defined a custom message: `uint8[] data`

The custom message is imported in my Node class with no problems: `from my_shared.msg import MyMessage`

In the same Node, I create the publisher with: `self.my_publisher = self.create_publisher(MyMessage, 'topic_in', 200)`

and I publish the message with: `self.my_publisher.publish(my_msg)`

my_msg is built in the following way:

```py
payload_bitstream = np.fromstring(my_data, np.uint8)
my_msg = payload_bitstream.tolist()
```

Sadly, I get a `TypeError: File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rclpy/publisher.py", line 68, in publish raise TypeError() TypeError`

Could you help out with this if you know what I am doing wrong pls?

Thanks in advance, G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your assignment of `my_msg`, which is an instance of the class `MyMessage` containing attributes defined in the `my_shared.msg` file, namely `my_msg.data` which has type of `uint8[]`. It's correct that you did `payload_bitstream.tolist()` to get a list of native python ints with uint8 values, but you need to assign it to the `data` attribute. TL;DR:

```py
my_msg.data = payload_bitstream.tolist()
```